# how to scrape text from <p> without getting unnecessary part in this structure?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

website code looks like this:

```
<ul class="article-list">
  <li>
    <p class="promo">
      "sentence sentence sentence sentence"
      <a class="readmore" href="https://link.blahblah.com"> Read more >> </a>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried

```
ul = soup.find_all("ul", class_= "article-list")  
for elem in ul:
    lis = elem.find_all("li")
    for x in lis:
        preview = x.find("p", class_="promo").get_text()
```

this returns

```
"sentence sentence sentence sentence     Read more"
```

How can I return "sentence sentence sentence sentence" only without "Read more"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find_next()` method with `text=True` parameter:

```
data = '''<ul class="article-list">
<li>
<p class="promo">
"sentence sentence sentence sentence"
<a class="readmore" href="https://link.blahblah.com"> Read more >> </a>
</p>
</li>
</ul>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('p.promo').find_next(text=True))
```

Prints:

```
"sentence sentence sentence sentence"
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure though

```
preview = x.find("p", class_="promo").a.text
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding to a list

```
soup = bs(resp, 'html.parser')

ul = soup.find_all("ul", class_= "article-list")
preview = []
for elem in ul:
    lis = elem.find_all("li")
    for x in lis:
        preview = x.find("p", class_="promo")
        preview.append(x.text)
```